# How to test confirm/alert messages with capybara + headless chrome

Tags: capybara, alert, confirm, google-chrome-headless

Recently I switched my acceptance tests from capybara-webkit to headless chrome. In some cases I need to check alert messages (for example, confirm to discard changes when user leaves the page). With capybara-webkit I did it the following way

```
confirm_messages = page.driver.browser.confirm_messages
expect(confirm_messages.first).to include "Do you want to discard your changes?"

# or

expect(page.driver.browser.confirm_messages).to be_empty
```

Now when I try to get confirm messages with chrome/headless chrome I get the following error:

```
undefined method `confirm_messages' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x007fa5478d8a08> (NoMethodError)
```

How can I test alerts with capybara and headless chrome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `text` parameter of Capybaras modal handling methods (`accept_confirm`/`accept_alert`/etc) -https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session#accept_confirm-instance_method - which will check the message before it accepts/dismisses the system modal

```
accept_confirm "Do you want to discard your changes?" do
  # whatever action triggers the modal to be shown
  click_link("Go somewhere else")
end
```

Technically `accept_confirm` also returns the text of the box so you could do something like

```
msg = accept_confirm do
  # action which triggers modal to be shown
end
expect(msg).to eq "Do you want to discard your changes?"
```

although if you know exactly the text of the message the first example reads better.  Note, this would also have worked with capybara-webkit without needing to use driver specific methods.